# Regex on delimited name-value pairs?

Tags: regex

I have a simple regex that I use to parse out the name-value pairs of a string, the name-value pairs are separated by equals signs and delimited by commas, for example:

Name1=Value1,Name2=Value2,Name3=Value3

This expression parses it perfectly

```
(?<key>[^=,]+)=(?<value>[^,]+)
```

except that if the comma or equals sign appears in either the name or value then it just truncates the string. So if I had

```
Name1=Value=1
```

it would match just

```
Name1=Value
```

How can I get it to discard the whole result as invalid instead of truncating it?

Comment: You may use - in C# or VB.NET - `^(?<key>[^=,]+)=(?<value>[^,]+)(?:,(?<key>[^=,]+)=(?<value>[^,]+))*$` and extract the captures from the two groups.

Comment: If you have the input `Name1=Value1,Name2=Value2,Name3=Value3,Name4=Value4=1`, should it return the first three pairs, or no pairs at all?

Comment: @mwp - well my initial expression handles the parsing out of the groups fine, its just that I wanted to also be able to apply it to the overall string and either fail or succeed based on that. So in your example, that should fail